# Request ajax with setInterval

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

I want to call ajax function at specified intervals after enterkey being pressed.
However, the code doesn't work.
I want to get some advice.
Thank you!

```
    function regist(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/getlabel',
      method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(r){
      // console.log(r);
      $('#label').text(r)
      console.log("ajax-success")
    }).fail(function(){
      console.log("ajax fail")
    });
}

function keyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        setInterval( regist() , 3000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific than "it doesn't work"? What error do you get?

Comment: You *pass* a function to setInterval, not call it. Ditch the parens.

Comment: In addition to *the code doesn't work* not being helpful, what is it that you are trying to accomplish? I mean, by the generics in your title.

Comment: common mistake: instead of `setInterval( regist() , 3000)` do `setInterval( regist , 3000)`

Comment: Oh sorry, the register() function is called only once after pressing the Enter key.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you very much! I solved it :)